# Is Limit call rate by subscription supported in Consumption tier?

Tags: azure-api-management

I am trying to add a rate-limit policy for an API management (per [API Management access restriction policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies#LimitCallRate)) and I am not sure if I do something wrong or if documentation is not correct.

According to the documentation, the

- Set usage quota by key
- Limit call rate by key

are not available in consumption tier, but *Limit call rate by subscription* has no such notice, so it should work (plus *Set usage quota by subscription* can be set).

I have an Azure API Management, I have created a sample API and a product and in the policy of the product is:

```
<policies>
<inbound>
    <base />
    <quota calls="100" renewal-period="86400" />        
    <rate-limit calls="20" renewal-period="90" />  
</inbound>
<backend>
    <base />
</backend>
<outbound>
    <base />
</outbound>
<on-error>
    <base />
</on-error>
</policies>
```

When I click on Save, I get

> One or more fields contain incorrect values:
>
> ```
> Error in element 'rate-limit' on line 16, column 10: Policy is not allowed in this sku 'Consumption'
> ```

Is there a way to set the rate-limit (=am I missing something) for consumption tier or is the documentation not correct?

Comment: Have you added closing tag for </policies> in your document as I don't see it.

`rate-limit` should work in consumption tier. I tried the same policy with my APIM instance hosted on consumption tier and it worked without any error:

Comment: Closing tag was missing, because of SO formatting. I have fixed the post and tried again just to be sure - no change (https://i.imgur.com/O9kvfEs.png). What location have you tried? I have North Europe, maybe that's the problem.

Comment: I tried in south India. Can you try it in different location ?

Comment: I can repro the issue when deployed it in North Europe region. I will check this internally with APIM product group and update the thread with appropriate details.

Comment: I have tried southeast asia and it works there. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is an ongoing update, once complete (a few days at most) "rate-limit" will be enabled for Consumption SKU, "rate-limit-by-key" disabled.

Comment: It looks like recently something changed and rate-limit only accepts renewal-period of no more than 300s (at least on Consumption sku). Is there a reason behind that? We need one call per 900s limit on Consumption plan, and this 300s boundary hurts.

Comment: rate-limit always accepted renewal period up to 5 minutes. This limit is the same for all APIM tiers. quota policy accepts longer periods, but it behaves a bit differently.

Answer (score 2):

You can now use the rate-limit and quota tag in policies at API level.

```
<policies>
        <inbound>
            <base />
            <rate-limit calls="5" renewal-period="60" remaining-calls-variable-name="remainingCallsPerSubscription" />
        </inbound>
        <backend>
            <base />
        </backend>
        <outbound>
            <base />
        </outbound>
        <on-error>
            <base />
        </on-error>
    </policies>
```

Using quotas:

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <quota calls="10000" renewal-period="3600" />
    </inbound>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
</policies>
```

Edit: on the consumption tier you can only apply these policies on API level. (So they apply to everyone that uses the API)