# .NET 7 Rate Limiting in Azure Function

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions

Is there a way to use .NET 7 Rate Limiting on Azure Function v4 (dotnet-isolated) HttpTrigger?

I've added RateLimiter in my ConfigureServices like this:

```
var builder = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices(s =>
    {
        // ...
        
        s.AddRateLimiter(_ =>
        {
            _.AddPolicy("myfunction", httpContext =>
                RateLimitPartition.GetSlidingWindowLimiter(httpContext.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"],
                _ => new SlidingWindowRateLimiterOptions
                {
                    AutoReplenishment = true,
                    PermitLimit = 1,
                    Window = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)
                }));
        });
    })
    .Build();
```

and

```
 [Function("myfunction")]
 [EnableRateLimiting("myfunction")]
 public async Task<IActionResult> MyFunction(
     [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequestData req)
 { // ...
 }
```

I'm pretty sure it shouldn't even work like this, but just to give an example of the scenario. My architecture is Azure Static Web App --> API Management (NOTE! consumption plan) --> Azure Function, and I can get the valid client IP from the `X-Forwarded-For` header in the Azure Function, but

So, is it possible to apply the rate limiting policy to a Azure Function on a function level?

Thanks!

Comment: why dont you use rate limiting in your APIM? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54832919/is-limit-call-rate-by-subscription-supported-in-consumption-tier

Comment: I have consumption plan APIM, and I'd very much like to have a IP based rate limiter instead of API based, like it is with consumption plan APIM.

Answer (score 1):

As @*Silent* mentioned, you can use rate-limiting policy in Azure APIM Consumption Plan.

You can import multiple Function APIS to the Azure APIM Service and can add the Rate-limiting policy to each API Level.
[image]

> I have consumption plan APIM, and I’d very much like to have a IP based rate limiter instead of API based, like it is with consumption plan APIM

I understand that you need to limit the number of requests per IP basis. If yes and this is the scenario, we have “IP address throttling” concept to limit the requests/API Calls from the IP address as mentioned in this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-sample-flexible-throttling) of Custom key-based throttling in Rate-limiting policy.

**Note:**

Yes, the `rate-limit-by-key` is not available in APIM Consumption Plan.

Comment: rate-limit-by-key is not available in consumption plan of APIM.

Comment: Yes @JussiPalo, forgot to mention that rate-limit-by-key is not available in consumption plan.

Comment: Just to point out that APIM only available for SWA APIs with the Standard plan, currently almost 20US$/month

Answer (score 1):

Just [ported ThrottlingTroll to Azure Functions](https://github.com/scale-tone/ThrottlingTroll/tree/main/ThrottlingTroll.AzureFunctions#throttlingtrollazurefunctions) (.NET 7 Isolated).

Works as an Azure Functions Middleware.

Supports

- [ingress throttling](https://github.com/scale-tone/ThrottlingTroll/tree/main/ThrottlingTroll.AzureFunctions#how-to-use-for-ingress-throttling) (returning `429 TooManyRequests` or impeding
  responses from HTTP-triggered functions),
- [egress throttling](https://github.com/scale-tone/ThrottlingTroll/tree/main/ThrottlingTroll.AzureFunctions#how-to-use-for-egress-throttling) (an
  HttpClient that limits itself) and
- propagating `429 TooManyRequests`
  [from egress to ingress](https://github.com/scale-tone/ThrottlingTroll/tree/main/ThrottlingTroll.AzureFunctions#to-propagate-from-egress-to-ingress).

Configurable [via host.json, programmatically or dynamically (by periodically reloading rate limits from whatever external config store without restarting the service)](https://github.com/scale-tone/ThrottlingTroll/tree/main/ThrottlingTroll.AzureFunctions#how-to-configure).

Stores counters in memory [or in a distributed cache](https://github.com/scale-tone/ThrottlingTroll/tree/main/ThrottlingTroll.AzureFunctions#how-to-specify-a-rate-counter-store-to-be-used).

Install from NuGet:

```
dotnet add package ThrottlingTroll.AzureFunctions
```

and then configure like this:

```
builder.ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults((hostBuilderContext, workerAppBuilder) => {

    workerAppBuilder.UseThrottlingTroll(hostBuilderContext, options =>
    {
        options.Config = new ThrottlingTrollConfig
        {
            Rules = new[]
            {
                new ThrottlingTrollRule
                {
                    UriPattern = "myfunction",

                    LimitMethod = new FixedWindowRateLimitMethod
                    {
                        PermitLimit = 1,
                        IntervalInSeconds = 5
                    },

                    // Identifying clients by their IP addresses
                    IdentityIdExtractor = request =>
                    {
                        request.Headers.TryGetValue("x-forwarded-for", out var clientIpAddress);
                        return clientIpAddress;
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    });
});
```